# yii2 AutoComplete position

Tags: yii2, jquery-ui-autocomplete

It was working perfectly, I have changed nothing, and I have realized that my AutoComplete widget is showing up not there where it was before (it was in the gridView, right underneath the filter textinput where it is expected). Now it shows up in the left upper corner of the page, with the first 2-3 options covered by the navbar. Is there a change in AutoComplete, or in Yii2 now? I have found an option `appendTo` that has maybe something to do with the problem, and I have done experiments with it but no luck, either it doesn't show up, or still on the wrong place. I have found nothing else relevant.

Here is my code in the gridview:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'contentOptions' => ['nowrap' => 'nowrap'],
    'filter' => AutoComplete::widget([
        'model' => $searchModel,
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'source' => Pl::find()->allAutoCompleteName(),
            'autoFill' => true,
        ],
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    ]),
],
```

The id of the search field is `plsearch-name`

The **js**:

```
jQuery('#plsearch-name').autocomplete({"source":[{"value":"PE 150","label":"PE 150"}...],"autoFill":true});
```

If I'm setting the `appendTo` in `clientOptions` to `'#plsearch-name'`, then it doesn't show up at all, however it is correct, isn't it? I don't see any styling in it.

What also quite interesting is:

```
<input 
type="text" 
id="plsearch-name" 
class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" 
name="PlSearch[name]" 
autocomplete="off"/>
```

What is this **autocomplete="off"** doing there?

Can you please point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: inspect the autocomplete code in your browser to see what styles is defined for it!

Comment: Did you do a Update to Yii 2.0.13 ? I think there was an update of jQuery to 3.x which may be the reason.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui/issues/71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem is fixed here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui/commit/36468550d72bce9d963149abe85b13ea2f3a8c18

The JQuery UI Version should be updated to 1.12

```
"require": {
         "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.4",
-        "bower-asset/jquery-ui": "1.11.*@stable"
+        "bower-asset/jquery-ui": "~1.12.1"
     },
```